# PHP 301 redirect to defined URL

Tags: php

I am attempting to redirect a user based on a defined URL.

If the defined URL contains `www` and the request URL **does not** contain `www` then the user is redirected to the `www` version of the URL.

If the defined URL does not contain `www` and the request URL **does** contain `www`, then the user is redirect to the non-`www` version of the URL.

It also needs to consider subdomain and path.

I have tried the following:

```
define(URL, 'localhost.com/cms');

$request = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if (get_subdomain(URL) != get_subdomain($request)) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", true, 301);
    header('Location:' . URL . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

function get_subdomain($url){
    $sub = parse_url($url);
    return $sub['host'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Haley. Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Questions asking for code should at least contain some code or a description of the attempts that were already made.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King  
what I tried as following, it have some problem.
define(URL, 'http://localhost.com/cms');
$request = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (get_subdomain(URL) != get_subdomain($request)) { 
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", true, 301); 
  header('Location:' . URL . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
}

function get_subdomain($url){
$sub = parse_url($url);
return $sub['host'];
}

Comment: you need to use for this .htaccess file, it can help you

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code you have defined a function AFTER you are attempting to call it. You need to place your function call above your `if` statement:

```
function get_subdomain($url){
    $sub = parse_url($url);
    return $sub['host'];
}

if (get_subdomain(URL) != get_subdomain($request)) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", true, 301);
    header('Location:' . URL . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

The `define` function requires a string for its first parameter. You are also missing the `http://` from your url.

The below will compare the path (e.g. `/cms`) to see if the user has requested the right page (otherwise they will be constantly redirecting), then compares the host. The host will contain the `www.` or other sub-domain bits.

I have made the `if` multi-line for readability.

```
define('URL', 'http://localhost.com/cms');

$request = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$urlParts = parse_url(URL);
$requestParts = parse_url($request);

if( $urlParts['path'] == $requestParts['path'] // Are we looking at the same pages
    &&
    $urlParts['host'] !== $requestParts['host'] // Check domain. Will also include sub-domain
) {
  // Failed check. Redirect to URL
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", true, 301);
  header('Location:' . URL);
}
```

The alternate solution is to do the above in the `.htaccess` file:

```
# If url begins with www, and we are on the right page, redirect to the non-www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.localhost\.com
RewriteRule ^cms% http://localhost.com/cms [R=301,L]
```